# Best way to process 1400 million records in SQL

Tags: performance, query-optimization, azure-sql

I humbly request you to help me with the below scenario, In my project I have to process time series data from a table. We are using Azure SQL Server.

The table `dbo.batch_events` has 1400 million rows, please see the below screenshot for the table structure and sample data:

[Source table structure and sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asqfE.png)

I have to pivot the equipment name from the `equipment_name` column in the `dbo.batch_events` table into column names and load the pivoted value into `dbo.time_series` table .

If I pivot the equipment name column, I am getting 685 columns to be created in the `dbo.time_series` table.

Please see the below screenshot showing the target table (`dbo.time_series`) structure and  expected output for the sample data shown in the source table.

[Target table structure and sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYlwC.png)

Please kindly advise what is the best approach and method to write the query in SQL.

The query I wrote is taking 25 hours to process the 1400 million records and load them into the target table.

I have created day wise partition on time_stamp column for the source table (`dbo.batch_events`) and created two nonclustered indexes - one on equipment name and the other on time stamp column.

I humbly request you to advise me on the best approach to write the query for this scenario.

The stored procedure I have created process one month of data at a time; for one month, we have around 120 million rows to deal with.

1. Used `While` loop to put entry for `start_date` and `end_date` for each month into `dbo.Iteration_ctrl` table, by getting the minimum and maximum date from the `dbo.Batch_events` table. So, I have 12 entries in this table, each entry representing one month.
2. Used `while` loop to iterate through the 12 `start_date` and `end_date` entries in the `dbo.Iteration_ctrl` table, and used pivot query inside the while loop to load the data into `dbo.Time_series` table.

Please see the stored procedure I have written, which is taking 25 hours (which seems to me inefficient). Any help would be appreciated please.

```
DECLARE @MIN_TIME DATETIME, @MIN_TIMESTAMP  DATETIME;
DECLARE @MAX_TIME DATETIME, @MAX_TIMESTAMP  DATETIME;
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME, @ROWCOUNT INT, @TOTALCOUNT INT;

SELECT @MIN_TIME = MIN(Time_stamp)  
FROM [dbo].[BATCH_EVENTS] 

SELECT @MAX_TIME = MAX(Time_stamp)  
FROM [dbo].[BATCH_EVENTS] 

PRINT 'INSERT INTO  TABLE  [dbo].[ITERATION_CTRL] HAS STARTED ' + CAST(GETDATE() AS nvarchar(30)) 

WHILE @MIN_TIME < @MAX_TIME
BEGIN
    SELECT @DATE = DATEADD(MM, 01, @MIN_TIME)             
    SELECT @DATE = CASE WHEN @DATE > @MAX_TIME THEN @MAX_TIME ELSE @DATE END            

    INSERT INTO dbo.ITERATION_CTRL
        SELECT @MIN_TIME, @DATE

    PRINT 'INSERTION INTO TABLE  [dbo].[ITERATION_CTRL] HAS ENDED FOR'+ CAST(@MIN_TIME AS nvarchar(30)) + ' -' + CAST( @DATE AS nvarchar(30)) +' NO OF ROWS INSERTED :'+ CAST( @@ROWCOUNT AS nvarchar(30)) +' ' + CAST(GETDATE() AS nvarchar(30))      

    SELECT @MIN_TIME = DATEADD(SS, 01, @DATE)   
END

PRINT 'INSERT INTO  TABLE  [dbo].[Time_series_data] HAS STARTED ' + CAST(GETDATE() AS nvarchar(30))              

SELECT @TOTALCOUNT = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.ITERATION_CTRL 
SELECT @ROWCOUNT = 1

WHILE @ROWCOUNT <= @TOTALCOUNT
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @MIN_TIMESTAMP = MIN_DATE, 
        @MAX_TIMESTAMP = MAX_DATE  
    FROM dbo.ITERATION_CTRL 
    WHERE ID = @ROWCOUNT

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
       INSERT INTO dbo.Time_series_data
           SELECT *
           FROM 
               (SELECT 
                    [Event_name], [Time_Stamp],
                    [Start_time], [End_time], [Duration],
                    [Value] AS [Sensor_Value],
                    Equipment_name
                FROM 
                    [dbo].[BATCH_EVENTS] BE
                WHERE 
                    Time_stamp >= [Start_time] AND Time_stamp <= [End_time]
                    AND Time_stamp BETWEEN @MIN_TIMESTAMP AND @MAX_TIMESTAMP) t
           PIVOT 
               (MAX([Sensor_Value])
                    FOR Equipment_Name IN ([MY1102], [MY1138], [MY1180],
                                           [MY1164], [MY1176], [MY204],
                                           [MY324], [MY64B6])
          ORDER BY 
              [Time_Stamp], [Event_name]
  
        COMMIT TRANSACTION

        SELECT @ROWCOUNT = @ROWCOUNT + 1

        --PRINT @MIN_TIMESTAMP, @MAX_TIMESTAMP
        PRINT 'INSERTION INTO TABLE   [Time_series_data] HAS ENDED NO OF ROWS INSERTED :'+ CAST( @@ROWCOUNT AS nvarchar(30)) +' For duration ' + CAST( @MIN_TIMESTAMP AS nvarchar(30))+ '   '+  CAST( @MAX_TIMESTAMP AS nvarchar(30))+' Time '+ CAST(GETDATE() AS nvarchar(30));
    END
END
```